# How to glue description from my xml source in xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have question how to glue two or more description in this case.
Source code is here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <Document>
    <Number>739</Number>
    <Date>2017-05-31</Date>
    <Amount>204.46</Amount>
    <FormOfPayment>2</FormOfPayment>
    <Customer>
      <Id> 10000</Id>
      <Name>Auto Car Parts</Name>
    </Customer>
    <DocumentItems>
      <Item>
        <Amount>36.59</Amount>
        <Date>2017-05-31</Date>
        <SourceDoc>
          <Number>1571/05/2017/ZO</Number>
          <Date>2017-05-26</Date>
        </SourceDoc>
      </Item>
      <Item>
        <Amount>167.87</Amount>
        <Date>2017-05-31</Date>
        <SourceDoc>
          <Number>0491/05/2017/ZO</Number>
          <Date>2017-05-12</Date>
        </SourceDoc>
      </Item>
    </DocumentItems>
    </Document>
```

I can`t find some function in xslt 1.0 which I can glue node from section Document/DocumetItems/Item/SourceDoc/Number to one variable. The source code I should to get is in this example like this:

```
     <DocumentNumber>739</DocumentNumber>
     <DocumentDate>2017-05-31</DocumentDate>
     <Description>1571/05/2017/ZO, 0491/05/2017/ZO</Description>
```

Please help me with get Description like this. Maybe I can use for-each but how to do this?

Comment: Well you have the XPath spelled out for your elements so simply use that path as the `select` attribute of your `for-each` and output the context node with `value-of select="."` inside, followed by `<xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>` or preceded by `<xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>` to have your comma separator.

Comment: How exactly It sholud look like??

Answer (score 0):

See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/948Fn58 for a spelled out stylesheet, it uses

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Number | Date"/>
          <Description>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="DocumentItems/Item/SourceDoc/Number"/>
          </Description>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Number">
      <DocumentNumber>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </DocumentNumber>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Date">
      <DocumentDate>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </DocumentDate>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SourceDoc/Number">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```